# Como quitar dominio autorizado de Google Api Console

Tags: api

Estoy en proceso de verificación de mi app por parte de google, me han enviado el siguiente correo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé  a donde tengo que acceder para quitar el dominio autorizado del que me hablan, entro en Google API console pero no veo dicha opción. Alguien puede echarme una mano? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema indica que en alguna de tus credenciales que definiste para un proyecto en [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/) definiste un dominio el cual no podrás verificar su titularidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Debes ingresar un dominio y verificar que tu eres el dueño o que tienes acceso a su administración, si definiste "google.com" como tu dominio no lo podrás verificar.**

Si no se puede verificar el dominio de otra forma tu proyecto no podrá activar las APIs que usarías en tu aplicación, esto es parte de las nuevas políticas de privacidad y usos de datos necesarias para darle a los usuarios transparencia en relación a los datos.